# Can we hook in an API call on save of a 2sxc content item and save results to a field?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Okay, a question for all you 2sxc users.  Let's say we want to build a Google Map with markers for various locations.  Easy enough, but if we want to use 2sxc for entering the locations, we'd like to on each save, have it obtain the lat/lng from the Geocoder API, and store that information into fields for that location content type.  Is this possible?  If so, do you have any examples or guidance on how to hook the API call in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick video of the content-type, GPS fields, and input (GPS Picker) that are in 2sxc nowadays. [Quick screen recording](https://accuraty-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/p/jfarrance/EaKCXP6wCRZPo9gTlXdV-IoB9sK1a1-ilphFFRo6lfG9UQ?e=JomqCh).

Comment: Thank you so much Jeremy - this works perfectly and I had no clue this hidden gem was even in there!  :)

Comment: I second David's comments.  I'm ready to dig in an make a somewhat messy solution I have so much nicer now!

Answer (score 2):

Just for those new to the GPS picker - the original version stored the values as numbers in separate number fields.

The newer implementation stores a json, and in Razor you can do `AsDynamic(content.Gps)` and then access properties like

```
    // GPS is a JSON field, so we must use AsDynamic to access the properties
    var gps = AsDynamic(content.GPS);
    var gpsLong = gps.Longitude ?? 0; // use 0 if not defined
    var gpsLat = gps.Latitude ?? 0;   // use 0 if not defined
```